# React .map() not displaying data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've done a very similar code to this and it has worked, however, I am getting nothing from this. Where console.log data I see the correct array of objects but where I console.log user I get nothing and the User component does not get called. When I plug in different static values for User it works

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import User from './user';

export default class UserResults extends Component {
  render() {
    let data = this.props.data;
    let results;
    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
      results = data.map(user => {
        console.log(user);
        return (
          <User key={user.name}
            stream={user.stream}
            name={user.name}
            logo={user.logo}
            url={user.url} />
        );
      })
    }
    return (
      <tbody className="UserResults">
        {results}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what is shown when I logged data

```
0:{stream: null, name: "storbeck", logo: null, url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/storbeck"}
1:{stream: null, name: "FreeCodeCamp", logo: "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/fre…decamp-profile_image-d9514f2df0962329-300x300.png", url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/freecodecamp"}
2:{stream: null, name: "OgamingSC2", logo: "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/oga…ngsc2-profile_image-9021dccf9399929e-300x300.jpeg", url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/OgamingSC2"}
3:{stream: null, name: "habathcx", logo: "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/habathcx-profile_image-d75385dbe4f42a66-300x300.jpeg", url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/habathcx"}
4:{stream: null, name: "RobotCaleb", logo: "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/robotcaleb-profile_image-9422645f2f0f093c-300x300.png", url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/RobotCaleb"}
5:{stream: {…}, name: "ESL_SC2", logo: "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/esl_sc2-profile_image-d6db9488cec97125-300x300.jpeg", url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ESL_SC2"}
6:{stream: null, name: "cretetion", logo: "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/cretetion-profile_image-12bae34d9765f222-300x300.jpeg", url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/cretetion"}
7:{stream: null, name: "noobs2ninjas", logo: "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/noo…ninjas-profile_image-34707f847a73d934-300x300.png", url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/noobs2ninjas"}
```

Here is the code for user.js incase you need to see it as well

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class User extends Component {
  render() {
    let props = this.props;
    console.log(props);
    let message;
    if (props.stream !== null) {
      message = 'Online';
    } else {
      message = 'User is offline';
    }
    return (
      <tr className="User">
        <td><img src={props.logo} alt={props.name} /></td>
        <td><a href={props.url}>{props.name}</a></td>
        <td>{message}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing stands out; without anything else to go on it's hard to say. Creating a minimal working example might be helpful, or at least the data you're attempting to map.

Comment: When I plug in different static values for User it works. Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: No. If the user component isn't being instantiated it's likely the shape of the `data` property, e.g., there's nothing to map over. What's in the console? What does `data` actually look like?

Comment: It's an array of objects. Shows like [{ val: val1, obj: obj1},....]

Comment: Put actual data in the question, e.g., when you `console.log(data)` give an example of what's shown.

Comment: Added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the answer. Where I was doing the API call, I was setting the state asynchronously so the data actually had a length of 0 although it was not empty. I moved my setState call and got the desired output.

Comment: The other option is to explicitly handle the case where data hasn't been loaded yet (e.g., spinner/etc). In general I'd say that's the preferred solution, but glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one prop at a time. If you can `console.log(user.name)` inside the `map` try adding only that to `<User />`, uncomment where you use them inside the component as well so that you start as basic as you can and work yourself up to using all the props. Then you will figure out where it's acting up.

It's super weird that you're not getting an error if something is wrong.